# Float content outside of website width

Tags: css, css-float

I have a website which is 960px wide and want to put a picture outside of that on the right side.

Vimeo have done it on there homepage: http://vimeo.com
you can see a drawing of an origami bird that sticks outside the website width
without causing the screen to get horizontal scrollbars

How do they do this?!

[origami bird Floating outside of Vimeos layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omVJM.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## New answer:

After some further inquiry, it seems that a critical aspect was that the box/image would not cause horizontal scroll-bars, while the content would. This was an interesting trick applied by vimeo, and was quite sneaky.

It has to do with a combination of `min-width` on `body`, and `overflow-x: hidden` on a non-immediate parent of the box/image. When combined with `position: absolute`, and a negative `right`, this achieves the desired result.

### HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="width_wrap">
        <div class="crane"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

### CSS:

```
body
{
    min-width: 960px;
}

#wrap
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#width_wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: 400px;
}

.crane
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    right: -40px;
}
```

Here is a minimal Fiddle, with outlines such that you can see what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/rUj8s/2/
​

## Original answer:

The `position: absolute` answers will most likely work, but will also take the image/div out of the normal flow of the document. This might not be what you want.

What you *probably* want is a negative `margin-right`:

```
.your_picture {
    margin-right: -30px;
}
```

Or, perhaps `position: relative`, and a negative `right`

```
.your_picture {
    position: relative;
    right: -30px;
}
```

Or, lastly, `position: relative`, and a positive `left`

```
.your_picture {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}
```

This is why negative margins and relative positioning exist. To move things relative to where they would normally lie.

Comment: No matter what I do I'm still getting scroll bars as the content is being counted as outside of the layout: http://wireframebox.com/linkto/website/jsfiddle_outside_content_issue.jpg

You can float content out the left side and it works, just not out the right

Comment: Edited to include explanation of more specific problem, as well as the real, true answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.your_picture {
  position:absolute;
   /* this needs to be negative to have the image sticking outside of the width */
  right:-30px;
}
```

Comment: what is the result that you saw?

Answer (score 0):

```
#parentDiv{
  position: relative;
}

#your_picture {
  position:absolute;
  right:-30px; /*change it to a number that you like */
  top: 30px; /*change it to a number that you like */
}
```

html markup would go like:

```
<div id="parentDiv">
   <div id="your_picture"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The green square counts to the width, try scaling the box left and right.

http://jsfiddle.net/QgYUt/